# Regularity of Baire measure

Tags: measure-theory

A [book](https://archive.org/details/banachspacesofan032699mbp) I am reading says that if X is a locally compact Hausdorff space, the Baire measure is regular, i.e. the measure of a Baire set is the infimum of the measures of open sets containing the Baire set. The author defines a Baire measure to be a map from the Baire sets to [0, $\infty$] satisfying the usual $\sigma$-additivity. I could not find a proof of this statement anywhere. Any reference or a proof would be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is Theorem G (in §52 of chapter 10) in   [Halmos, Paul R. "Measure Theory, volume 18 of Graduate Texts in Mathematics." (1974).](https://books.google.dk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jS_vBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA2&dq=measure+theory+halmos&ots=JawUU9gtJT&sig=O2gh-GVGSk8o1Jrv4ZRP_OHwyAY&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=every%20baire%20measure&f=false)

Comment: Thanks. The book also contains a detailed discussion of Baire and Borel sets, exactly what I need.